# select 10 greater than and 10 lesser than an integer value in db2.

Tags: sql, database, select, db2, union

I want to write a select statement which will return 10  rows having the column value greater than an input integer and 10 rows having the column value lesser than an input integer.

Comment: Any 10 rows, or the 10 rows right above and below the integer value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution, if you like:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by (case when col < target_val then 'lower' else 'higher' end),
                                order by abs(target_val - col)
                               ) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE Column > 100 FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE Column < 100 FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```